# How to merge specific branches with git?

Tags: git, github

*Note: this is somehow linked to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27355333/1422096) but it requires additional attention to branches.*

Let's say I have a Github project https://github.com/basjj/myproject.git  with 2 branches (`master` and `feature1`) and a local repository on my computer.

A user named `blah` proposed a pull-request. He has 3 branches (`master`, `feature1`, `feature2`) on https://github.com/blah/myproject.git.

## Case #1

I would like to try his `feature2` branch here on my computer, slightly modify it, and merge it into my own `master`. **Are the following commands correct?**

```
git checkout -b feature2
git pull https://github.com/blah/myproject.git   # it pulls only his feature2 branch or all?
# review the new files, make changes, etc.
git add .
git commit
git checkout master
git merge feature2
```

Does the 2nd line (`git pull...`) pull all of his branches or only his `feature2`?
Something else: will user `blah` appear in Github's [contributor list](https://github.com/blog/643-contributors) or not?

## Case #2

I would like to try his `feature1` branch here on my computer, slightly modify it, and merge it into my own `master`. **How to do it, given that I already have a `feature1` branch myself, that I don't want to overwrite(!) ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All branches are in their own namespaces, based on the remote name.

So it is best to add a remote for the repo you want to try out:

```
git remote add blah https://github.com/blah/myproject.git
```

Then you can fetch from blah

```
git fetch blah
```

And create your `feature2` from `blah/feature2`:

```
git checkout -b feature2 blah/feature2
```

As for `feature1`, you can simply merge `blah/feature1` to your `master`.
Or you can create your own local branch:

```
git checkout -b blah_feature1 blah/feature1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. `All branches are in their own namespaces, based on the remote name.` what does this mean, can you explain a bit more (maybe with one example)? `git fetch blah` will this download all 3 branches of user `blah`?

Comment: @Basj yes, it downloads all three branches and store them in your `.git/refs/remotes/blah` (hence the namespace notion)

Comment: Something else: are my commands for `case #1` correct as well? Will the user `blah` appear in contributors with my commands? with yours?

Comment: @Basj That means blah/feature1 is completely different of your current existing and local `.git/refs/heads/feature1` branch.

Comment: @Basj I fear that in your case1 your local `feature2` branch does not track properly `blah/feature2`. By naming the remote `blah`, you can explicitly state where the local branch `feature2` should point to: `blah/feature2`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try this asap. BTW: the only way to be able to test this I can see is to create a 2nd github account, just to be able to test how I can do a PR / merge a PR / etc. Do you see another way to sandbox PRs / merging / etc. ?

Comment: @Basj in your case, a second repo is clearer. You could in theory make pull request from the same repo(!), but for your test, a separate account forking your repo in a separate repo will help you separate who does what.

Comment: Thanks. Last question: do you know a good tutorial that explains the basic vocabulary (I have seen lot but nothing really super great), for example what is the `blah/feature2` syntax? (is `blah` named the remote in this case?) and which would cover such questions as here for example as well?

Comment: @Basj I like http://learngitbranching.js.org/, but https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-checkout is a good introduction

Comment: Thanks again @VonC. I tried your commands and the ones recommended by the GitHub interface. I still have this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40613414/1422096