# User who made Pull Request doesn't appear in Contributor List after merge

Tags: git, github

I have a repo `Test`. GitHub informed me that user `woo27`, who forked my repo `Test`, has done a pull-request, and these are the official recommended commands (see screenshot below) to merge:

```
git checkout -b woo27-master master
git pull https://github.com/woo27/Test.git master
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff woo27-master
git push origin master
```

**I did exactly these commands, and merged. I works, but then `woo27` doesn't appear in the contributor list, nor in the list of people who modified the files. Why? How to solve this?**

[image]

*(This has nothing to do with a 1-day delay, I have already had the same problem before)*

---

[image]

Comment: Note: I have read [this](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/) but still don't find the solution.

Comment: Example: here 21 contributors on a single file: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/View/Factory.php

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to ask the person who is doing the pull request to do:

```
git config user.email "your_email@example.com"
```

with the same email as the one used for the GitHub account.

Source: https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git/

Then it will work.

[image]