# Received a pull-request from someone else, how to edit it before merging directly on github?

Tags: github, pull-request

(For reference, here is a command line `git` solution [How to handle review a pull-request, modify code, and merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27355333/how-to-handle-review-a-pull-request-modify-code-and-merge))

Here I'm looking for a 100% in-browser solution directly in the Github interface.

- I have a repo `foobar`
- I receive a pull request from user `bob`
- I would like to make a few tiny edits on his modifications, and merge this PR

**How to do this 100% from the Github interface, without having to open a command-line and do `git ...` operations?**

Note: I don't want to merge `bob`'s as it is, and do modifications later in a further commit. I would like to edit his PR before merging it to my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First go in the *Files changed* tab of the pull request. There you could edit the files with the *Edit file* button.

[image]

That works if you have write access to the repo and the pull request author enables *Allow edits by maintainers*. (Enabled by default)

[image]

The checkbox could also be checked or unchecked after creating the pull request.

Comment: Thanks @Julian! Can I ask someone who made a PR in the past to add this check *a posteriori*, so that I can edit and merge?

Comment: Yes after creating the pull request,  you could check or uncheck the checkbox. Just tested it.

Comment: @Basj you github link wont work (404). Guess its private?

Comment: It's just a dummy URL just to give future readers an idea of what the URL should look like