# Prevent TFS from adding new commits to open pull request?

Tags: git, tfs, merge, pull-request

I have a git repository in my TFS 2013 server.

I created a Pull Request 5 days ago, from my personal branch to the shared 'develop' branch.

Since then, I've continued developing on other features, and pushed the commits to my branch on the server.  I'm not ready to merge these into the develop branch yet.

The pull request hasn't been approved yet, but now shows all of my subsequent commits being included in the pull request.

How do I stop TFS doing this?

(from other questions, like this one: [github: Adding commits to existing pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147445/github-adding-commits-to-existing-pull-request) other git hosts behave like I'm expecting - you need to specifically *try* to add a commit to a pull request).

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You had an expected behavior of Pull Request. If you don't want to add new commits to open pull request, you can create another topic branch for your personal branch.

Comment: I second the OP - not only my own commits get added. If the branch is shared, then other people's commits are added too automatically. It seems wrong to us, because it assumes all the developers working on the same shared branch know when a PR on the branch is outstanding and would all switch to another temp branch until the PR is over and then rebase back to the shared branch. This is mental. We need a way to explicitly control whether new commits are to be added to the PR.