# Editing files as a collaborator on GitHub

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I am trying to make changes to a GitHub repository for which I have been invited as a collaborator. I can create new files and modify them, but when I try to make any changes to an existent file, I see this message saying:

> You must be on a branch to make or propose changes to this file

[image: See this screenshot]

Then only after I push a commit through the terminal, I am able to modify this file on GitHub. Is this an expected behavior?

Comment: I suggest reading up on "GitHub Flow" which is the usual use model for git when hosted on GitHub: summary: branch, make changes, submit PR.

Comment: Thank you, I will do @Richard

Comment: Thanks @Richard, never saw that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like the repository you're using has protected their main branch (usually `master`). This is usually because they want changes to be done with a pull request-based workflow to ensure code review and CI cleanliness before merging.

When you create a branch on the command line and push it, you should be able to modify it as normal, since it's not a protected branch. Similarly, if you create a branch through the UI, you should also be able to edit it. However, you won't be able to push directly to the main branch or edit it directly in the UI.

Comment: I my case, I have tripled checked and the master branch doesn't seem to be protected (or I can't find how to remove this protection since I'm admin of the repo). But what's even more surprising is that for some files, editing will be available while, for other it won't. I'm guessing it depends on the file format, but no documentation is to be found anywhere. :( 
Anyone has insights on this?

Answer (score 18):

I got it:

I came to the source file using the search, hence the result I got was on a [specific commit](https://github.com/organisation/repo/blob/252e66a59e1b717df6b4467e4de025fcfd254a88/pages/file.ext).

Changing the tree [image: the tree] to the master branch: [image: master branch] restores the ability to edit the file.

Comment: +1 this worked for me (though these days the name `main` is used for the master branch on some projects).