# GitHub: adding commits to existing pull request using Web browser (no git command)

Tags: github

I created a pull request on GitHub and, after receiving comments, I would like to add more commits to it, by modifying different files.

Is it possible to do it with a Web browser only, without access to the `git` command?

Also, consider that I am *not* the owner of the repository.

Note that the answers to the question [github: Adding commits to existing pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10147445/3753826)
 do not address my question, as they use `git`, or deal with changing a single file.

Comment: Select the branch that is the subject of the pull request, make edits on any files you need to, and make the new commit.

Comment: This is the general approach. My question is about the Web interface. Could you please elaborate, in a full answer, on which GitHub menu one should use?

Comment: As far as I know there's no way to batch many individual file changes into a single commit using the web interface, but you can squash them during the PR merge.

Comment: Thanks. Does this produce the same end result? And what GitHub menu does one has to click on the Web interface? Full details about the buttons to click at the beginner level in a proper answer would be useful. But if this cannot be done in the browser, you can state it in an answer.