# Update pull request of deleted fork

Tags: git, github

So I first forked a repo and then made a commit to that forked repo. I then opened a pull request. The pull request listed all the changes I wanted. This was great. And then I've deleted my forked project.

But then repo owner said change something. But I've deleted my forked repo. I need to update that PR.

How should I handle it without creating new PR?

Comment: Did you delete the fork _before_ your pull request was completed?  You can always fork again, make a new change, and then issue a new pull request.

Comment: No no. My PR is created successfully, and after that I have deleted my fork.

Comment: I think the correct approach would be to simply create another branch, make the fix, and then issue a new pull request.