# How to make changes in an existing github PR?

Tags: git, github

I am working on a open source project. I forke it, downloaded it, used it, found some issues, modified and sent a PR to upstream code. Now, they want me to make some changes, and I am not sure how to do that in the existing PR?

Can anyone please help me do that? TIA.

Comment: A duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790448/how-to-update-a-pull-request

Answer (score 2):

> Now, they want me to make some changes, and I am not sure how to do that in the existing PR?

Simply commit your new changes to the branch which the PR is pointing to and you will see the updates in the BR automatically.

This is the concept of the PR. Update your code as many times as you need and commit them. All your changes will be reflected in the Pr.

For example look on hit. multiple commits were made to the branch:

https://github.com/github/linguist/pull/2843/commits