# github - Update an unmerged pull request with upstream master ahead by several commits

Tags: git, github

I had forked a repo and opened a pull request, which is still unmerged.

Now, I need to make more changes to it. I saw couple of questions here, viz., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790448/how-to-update-a-pull-request-from-forked-repo), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947322/preferred-github-workflow-for-updating-a-pull-request-after-code-review) that mention that I can simply commit and the pull request will be updated.

In my case, the upstream `master` has gone several commits ahead of my `master` branch (I had committed to `master` itself, rather than to some feature branch, my bad!). If I simply add one more commit to my `master` branch, will it still reflect at the bottom of the pull request discussion, and will the owner be still able to merge it? Or should I close this pull request, rebase my `master` branch with the latest `upstream` `master` and then make a fresh pull request ?

Comment: you can commit the changes to your branch and pull from the upstream master, that way you would be in sync with the master

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri thanks! will try that.. but will it appear in the PR discussion?

Comment: You would need to push those changes and it should appear in the PR

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update a GitHub forked repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-do-i-update-a-github-forked-repository)