# can I add a commit after a PR is raised?

Tags: git

I have commit ad push 3 files: file1, file2, and file3. What would happen if I checked in and push an updated version of file1? would the latest commmit and push file1 still be included in the same PR?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update a pull request from forked repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790448/how-to-update-a-pull-request-from-forked-repo)

Comment: Since you're asking about a Pull Request, I assume you're pushing to Github?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pull requests aren't a native feature of Git, so how they work depends on the hosting platform you're using.  Since you haven't told us which one you'd like to know about, I'm going to guess it's GitHub, and you can try on your own platform if it's different.

On GitHub, it is possible to add an additional commit or to modify commits simply by pushing to the branch (including force-pushing if necessary).  Whatever is in the branch with the pull request on the server will be part of the pull request.