# How to rewrite history in git?

Tags: git

I cloned a project repository and did some commits to it. The commits were pretty dirty; I messed up tabs-spaces and committed some trash along the way. So before making a pull request I want to make things tidy. I think the best way would be making a new branch at `origin/master` and then apply commits from my old branch one by one to a working copy and doing clean commits to a new branch.

So how to apply commit from other branch to a working copy? 
Is it the best way to do it? Such task seems pretty common and maybe there is already an established workflow and tools for such things?

Comment: see [cleaning commit history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947322/preferred-github-workflow-for-updating-a-pull-request-after-code-review/15055649#15055649) - the command you are effectively looking for is [rebase](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing).

Comment: I don't want to just sqash my commits (as in provided answer); I want to edit each commit before applying it to fix things

Comment: It's the same process, and still using rebase. (try it/read about it before commenting).

Comment: Ah I see. It's a good thing to read a manual first ^_^. Thank you I think this is the answer.

Comment: See http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the work tree is something like:

[image: img]

and you want to apply **only `g-h`** to the `origin/master`. First off, create a new branch using `origin/master`, and another for commits upto `h` only:

```
git checkout -b new-branch origin/master
git checkout -b daughter-branch h
```

Now, apply commits from `g` onwards

```
git rebase --onto new-branch g^
```