# Merge diff between two branches to third branch

Tags: git, diff

Assume I have two branches, `master` and `new_feature`

I was supposed to work on a specific feature, I thought this feature would be part of `new_feature` so, I checked out `specific_feature` branch out of the `new_feature` branch, like so

```
git checkout -b specific_feature
```

Now I did a lot development in this `specific_feature` branch, merged `upstream/new_feature` into it a couple of times to get the remote changes.

Now, I come to know that my `specific_feature` should have been branched out of `master` not `new_feature`. (`new_feature` branch is not ready to be pushed)

Is there a way I can take the diff between my `specific_feature` branch and `new_feature` branch, and apply those changes to new branch say `specific_feature_master` (branched out of master)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29136666/1190388

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That seems a job for [`git rebase --onto`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2369516/6309):

```
git rebase --onto master new_feature specific_feature
```

That will take only the commits *after* `new_feature` up to `specific_feature` HEAD, and replay them onto `master`.

Note that you will then have to force push specific_feature to upstream (if you already pushed it before): `git push --force specific_feature`.

That can be an issue if others have already pulled that branch and are working on it.

---

[davidriod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4569284/davidriod) correctly points out that:

> I don't think this will work as the OP as merged several times the `upstream/new_feature` branch in the specific_feature branch

If `new_feature` was never updated (fetch only, never pull), then it might still work.
If `new_feature` was updated (pull) and merged into `specific_feature`, then the `rebase --onto` would only play the last few commits since the last merge: here, only `z'` commits would be replayed, not the first `z`.

```
x--x--x
       \
        y--y--Y--y--y (new_feature)
            \  \
             z--M--z'--z' (specific_feature)
```

Instead of cherry-picking, I would:

- make `specific_feature` out of `master` (and mark the `specific_feature` branch as `tmp`)
- merge `Y` (the last `new_feature` commit which was merged in `specifc_feature`) into the new `specific_feature` branch

That is:

```
git checkout -b tmp specific_feature
git checkout -B specific_feature master
git merge $(git merge-base tmp new_feature) # that merges Y

        ----------M (specific_feature)
       /         /
x--x--x         /
       \       /
        y--y--Y--y--y (new_feature)
            \  \
             z--M--z'--z' (tmp)
```

Then the `rebase --onto` can use that same common ancestor `Y` as the correct base:

```
git rebase --onto specific_feature $(git merge-base tmp new_feature) tmp
git branch -D tmp

        ----------M--z''--z'' (specific_feature)
       /         /
x--x--x         /
       \       /
        y--y--Y--y--y (new_feature)
```

Comment: I don't think this will work as the OP as merged several times the upstream/new_feature branch in the specific_feature branch

Comment: @davidriod ok, I have edited the question to propose an alternative merge-based option (instead of cherry-picking, which I tend to avoid because of commit duplication (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2628915/6309)

Comment: @VonC I may have badly understood but basically this is a feature rescheduling which can happen in a project and no code at all from the new feature is supposed to be merged in the master branch. Regarding the commit duplication, it's not a real issue if the specific feature is supposed to get ridden off. Basically I think the OP just want to reconstruct the specific_feature **independantly** from the new_feature branch.

Answer (score 2):

You may use use the command git cherry to retrieve the commit done on the specific_feature branch and which does not appear on the origin/new_feature branch.

```
git cherry origin/new_feature specific_feature
```

You can then create a new branch from master and cherry-pick all these commits.
But if you dependencies between your development on specific_feature and origin/new_feature no scm is going to resolve that for you.

```
git checkout -b specific_feature_master master
git cherry origin/new_feature specific_feature | egrep '^+' | awk '{print $2} | xargs git cherry-pick
```

Something like that should do starting point for resolving your problem.

Comment: minor edit to the last line:

`git cherry origin/new_feature specific_feature | egrep '^\+' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs git cherry-pick`