# New Git branch with diff of 2 others

Tags: git, github, bamboo

I want to create a branch in GIT with the file differences from 2 other git branches. I do not want whole repo copy but only the changed files keeping rest of the folder structure as is. How can I achieve this?

For example:

*Branch 1: testbranch1*

```
deployment/src/main/apiproxy/myorg/folder1/file1.txt
deployment/src/main/apiproxy/myorg/folder1/file2.txt
deployment/src/main/apiproxy/myorg/folder2/file1.txt
deployment/src/main/apiproxy/myorg/folder2/file2.txt
```

*Branch 2: testbranch2*

```
deployment/src/main/apiproxy/myorg/folder1/file1.txt -> File Changed
deployment/src/main/apiproxy/myorg/folder1/file2.txt
deployment/src/main/apiproxy/myorg/folder2/file1.txt
deployment/src/main/apiproxy/myorg/folder2/file2.txt -> File Changed
```

*New branch should have:*

```
deployment/src/main/apiproxy/myorg/folder1/file1.txt
deployment/src/main/apiproxy/myorg/folder2/file2.txt
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you mean. Could you [edit] your question and provide an example, possibly as a [mcve]?

Comment: May be `git rebase --onto` ?! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29315281/merge-diff-between-two-branches-to-third-branch

Comment: Example added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new branch, You can just create a patch for the changes.

```
git format-patch testbranch2 --stdout > mypatch.patch
```

Later if you need to apply your patch, do the following.

```
git apply mypatch.patch
```

Comment: Thanks. I need a branch to put in Bamboo plan So that maven can build and deploy from that.
Can this patch be applied to a branch?

Comment: If the testbranch2 to contain latest changes, why don't you use that branch?  can you explain?

Comment: Yes. You need to checkout to the specific branch to apply the patch.

Comment: I can't use testbranch2 because it will deploy all files and not only the changed files.

Comment: I guess you can create a build step to apply the patch?

Comment: Would be great if you can help me how to do that in bamboo