# Squash git commits from topic branch

Tags: git

I have a topic branch (macaroni), and I have submitted a pull request. I had to make a change after feedback. It was requested that I squash the two commits into a single commit. This is what I have done:

```
git status
On branch macaroni

git log
commit def  feedback fixes
commit abc  fix cheddar flavor

git rebase -i origin/master
.. go through screen where I pick commit to squash ..
.. go through screen where I update commit message ..

git log
commit abc fix cheddar flavor, squashing done!
```

at this point I believe I have to push my topic branch using the -force flag, because I have changed history:

```
git push -f
```

I am using the second answer from this question:

[Preferred Github workflow for updating a pull request after code review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947322/preferred-github-workflow-for-updating-a-pull-request-after-code-review)

with subtitle "Optional - Cleaning commit history". The author mentions at the end that you should be using topic branches, not sure if I should have changed any of the commands since I'm already on a topic branch.

I am also concerned with accidentally force-pushing something onto the master branch with the above since I'm using -f, but since I'm on the topic branch, only that branch should be affected, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check what is going to happen with

```
git push -f --dry-run
```

if this looks ok, then do the real command with

```
git push -f
```

to see what branch would be affected with a push -f

```
git branch -vv --list macaroni
```

Comment: Ah yes, --dry-run.. ok that gives the following response which I'm not sure about: "fatal: The current branch macaroni has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin macaroni"

Answer (score 0):

If unsure, use explicit remote name and push spec when force pushing:

```
git push -f my-remote HEAD:macaroni
```

Answer (score 0):

The push command can behave differently depending on you configurations and also the git versions . For example, if you version is 1.X git push defaults to push all matching branches and in your scenario you **may** have pushed also the master branch.

The variable you need to check is:

```
push.default
```

You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948354/default-behavior-of-git-push-without-a-branch-specified#948397) post useful.