# git pull --rebase on public branches

Tags: git, rebase, pull

I have read that I should never rebase public branches. I'm unsure whether this also means that I shouldn't do git pull --rebase (of a feature branch where I collaborate with a colleague, and thus the branch is public). Can somebody please confirm that doing a git pull --rebase is fine in that case, and that the idea that a public branch should not be rebased is referring to not doing a rebase of the feature/origin onto a master?

To clarify again, I want confirmation that it's ok to do a pull --rebase, basically updating my local copy of the branch with the origin of it, rebasing my commits onto it.

Comment: Like `git pull --rebase origin master` ?

Comment: It's okay to do for topic branches, but not okay to branches like *master*.

Comment: I'm basically working on a feature branch

Comment: `git pull` = `git fetch` followed by a second Git command. The second command is normally `merge` but `--rebase` directs Git to run `git rebase` second. The branch that is rebased is *your* branch, specifically your *current* branch, with the `<upstream>` argument being the tip of whatever branch you fetched (normally your current branch's *upstream* setting, but it can get complicated depending on your arguments to `git pull`). This also invokes the *fork point* machinery, which is, well, complicated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, that's fine

Because doing that only rewrites your local commits ontop of the public history.

Rebasing itself isn't "the problem" with public branches, it's any workflow whereby you have to force-push to a public branch that's a concern.

See also:

- [Preferred Github workflow for updating a pull request after code review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947322/preferred-github-workflow-for-updating-a-pull-request-after-code-review/15055649#15055649)
- [When should I use git pull --rebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472254/when-should-i-use-git-pull-rebase/2472606#2472606)