# Push git branch with 1 commit

Tags: git, gitlab

The branches of my colleagues has only 1 commit every time. Mine, includes all other commits I made like changes and fixes. How to do that? Or does it means they really commit only once before pushing it. They said rebase it onto master but I tried couple ways of procedure to do it but nothing happens.

I tried

1.)

```
git pull (master)
git checkout feature-branch
git rebase master
```

Then fixed the conflicts and nothing happens still all my commit history are there.

2.)

```
git pull (master)
git checkout feature-branch
git rebase --onto feature-branch <specific commit ID>
```

Still same

Comment: Do you _mean_ 1 commit as asked (“ The branches of my colleagues has only 1 commit every time”) or do you mean when you create a pull request? It is not normal to have a repo with multiple different branches each containing one (implied, root) commit. It would help to show what you mean using git log. Please update the question to clarify.

Comment: Assuming pull request workflow: Does this answer your question? [Preferred Github workflow for updating a pull request after code review](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15055649/761202)

Comment: I have some issues understanding your question : "How to do that ?" does "that" refer to the fact that from what you see, your colleagues' changes are always grouped in one single commit ? Is your question: "How can I group all the changes on my branch in one single commit ?"

Comment: @AD7six this looks the answer for me. Yup exactly what I'm looking for thanks

Comment: What do you mean? Of course your branch will still contain your commits

Answer (score 1):

Third possibilities comes to my mind:

You didn't complete the `rebase` in the last step. Follow the messages that `git` produce. After resolving conflicts, you should probably `add`, `commit`, and `rebase --continue` in order to complete. If you use `git merge-tool` for conflict resolution, only `rebase --continue` may be enough.

Second thing is, even after successful rebase, your old commit is still in the repository. It just becomes unreachable if there is no other tag or branch pointing to it. You can ignore that.

Last thing is, after your `rebase`, you should `push` or create a `pull request` and get accepted in order to be seen on the remote repository.

Comment: After fixing conflicts I did add and rebase --continue it says success but the commits on my feature-branch are still there

Comment: After rebase, your `feature branch` will stay. It will just point to the rebased commit instead of the old commit.

Answer (score 0):

When you rebase, your commits will move to different parent. Your commits will get  new SHA1 and will stay. Only their parent gets changed.

Please see the below diagram, where blue commits move to different parent and the history looks more cleaner.

image reference: https://developpaper.com/

[image]