# How to remove the changes to one file in a pull request?

Tags: git

I did:

```
git clone <some repo>
git checkout development
git checkout -b my-feature
```

updated `somefolder/somefile.sh` and other files and did multiple commits, pushed the changes and did rebase:

```
git commit -a -m "somefile update"
git push origin my-feature
git rebase origin/development -i
```

and created a merge request in GitLab, but some reviewer requested to rollback all changes I made in `somefoler/somefile.sh` (in `my-feature` branch)

What is the right command for that?

Comment: What do you want to roll back? Did you change multiple files but want to undo only changes to somefolder/somefile.sh?

git reset development # This will discard all changes on your branch
git checkout development file.sh # This will bring back the file.sh from the development branch
git revert <commit hash> # This will revert one commit

after a git rebase develompent -i
you will need to do a git push -f

Comment: @drahnoel yes, changed multiple files and pushed them, but need to undo only changes to `somefolder/somefile.sh`

Comment: So then AD7six answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do this but the simplest is:

```
$ git fetch
$ git checkout origin/develop somefolder/somefile.sh
$ git commit -m "reset to develop" somefolder/somefile.sh
```

That creates a new commit undoing the effects of any previous commits in the branch to that one file.

---

An alternative approach is to rebase the change out, the ease of doing that depends on how the commits are composed. Please see "Cleaning commit history" in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15055649/76120) for a description of how to do that.