# How can I combine two commits into one commit?

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-svn, rebase

I have a branch 'firstproject' with 2 commits. I want to get rid of these commits and make them appear as a single commit.

The command `git merge --squash` sounds promising, but when I run `git merge --squash` my terminal just brings up options for the command. What is the correct command?

```
Commit 1:
Added 'homepage.html'
Added 'contacts.html'

Commit 2:
Added 'homepage.php'
Added 'homepage.php'
Deleted 'homepage.html'
Deleted 'contacts.html'
```

Comment: I don't think that's the right command. Also, I am doubting that you even can change commits like that.

Comment: Nah you can change multiple commits into one commit: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History  my question is just about the specific command for it.

Comment: @BSull You absolutely can changes commits in any way you want. They are completely editable at literally any time. If you're sharing code with others, doing so will rewrite your history and you'll effectively be working with a different branch than everybody else.

Comment: This should have never been duped. In fact, that other one should have been closed as too broad. The other question this is marked as a dupe of is needless complex as it involves abandoning a prior rebase.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

You want to `git rebase -i` to perform an [interactive rebase](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Changing-Multiple-Commit-Messages).

If you're currently *on* your "commit 1", and the commit you want to merge, "commit 2", is the previous commit, you can run `git rebase -i HEAD~2`, which will spawn an editor listing all the commits the rebase will traverse. You should see two lines starting with "pick". To proceed with squashing, change the first word of the second line from "pick" to "squash". Then save your file, and quit. Git will squash your first commit into your second last commit.

Note that this process rewrites the history of your branch. If you are pushing your code somewhere, you'll have to `git push -f` and anybody sharing your code will have to jump through some hoops to pull your changes.

Note that if the two commits in question *aren't* the last two commits on the branch, the process will be slightly different.

Comment: How to do `Then write your file, and quit`? I'm using Android Studio Terminal, git console itself Or even opened git console by SourceTree software. But how to save and quit?

Comment: How to combine 2 commits that aren't the last two commits on the branch?

Comment: Does it make any difference if I want to squash the 2nd into the 1st instead of the 1st into the 2nd as you describe?

Comment: @PandaWood that doesn't really make sense. A squashed into B is the same thing as B squashed into A. `(1 + 2) = (2 + 1)`.

Comment: @meagar I think it does make sense... if you check this issue (a duplicate of this), squashing 'direction' made a big difference and was the root of the entire issue (see the first comment with around 200 upvotes about 'squashing the wrong way') - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2568581/43453

Comment: @PandaWood You're misreading the answer. The first way was simple *wrong*, not *different*. You can *only* squash backwards, it makes no sense to think of squashing an older commit into a newer one, but if you *could* it would be the same operation.

Comment: I understood up to " change the first word of the second line" - second line of what?

Comment: What do you mean by "anybody sharing your code will have to jump through some hoops to pull your changes"?

Answer (score 114):

Lazy simple version for forgetfuls like me:

`git rebase -i HEAD~3`
or however many commits instead of 3.

Turn this

```
pick YourCommitMessageWhatever
pick YouGetThePoint
pick IdkManItsACommitMessage
```

into this

```
pick YourCommitMessageWhatever
s YouGetThePoint
s IdkManItsACommitMessage
```

and do some action where you hit `esc` then `enter` to save the changes. [1]

When the next screen comes up, get rid of those garbage # lines [2] and create a new commit message or something, and do the same `escape` `enter` action. [1]

Wowee, you have fewer commits. Or you just broke everything.

---

[1] - or whatever works with your git configuration. This is just a sequence that's efficient given my setup.

[2] - you'll see some stuff like `# this is your n'th commit` a few times, with your original commits right below these message. You want to remove these lines, and create a commit message to reflect the intentions of the n commits that you're combining into 1.

Comment: Very concise solution - thank you. Might be handy to outline that `s` used here stands for squash.  To use the commit, but meld into the previous commit

Comment: If you have just `2` commits and want to combine the same `2` commit, you will need to run `git reset --soft HEAD~` and `git commit --amend`.

Comment: @Stachu When I command push after this, It will ask for pull  and merge. What I can do to avoid that?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to pull and merge?

Comment: If you want to keep the commit message for `pick YourCommitMessageWhatever` and just merge the other commits into it, you can replace `s` with `f` (fixup). Don't forget to make sure your commits are in the correct order, so you don't get unexpected results! (use `git log -p` afterwards to see the log with changes)

Answer (score 33):

1. Checkout your branch and count quantity of all your commits.
2. Open git bash and write: `git rebase -i HEAD~<quantity of your commits>` (i.e. `git rebase -i HEAD~5`)
3. In opened `txt` file change `pick` keyword to `squash` for all commits, except first commit (which is on the top). For top one change it to `reword` (which means you will provide a new comment for this commit in the next step) and click SAVE! If in vim, press `esc` then save by entering `wq!` and press enter.
4. Provide Comment.
5. Open Git and make "Fetch all" to see new changes.

Done

Answer (score 20):

This is what I do. It's easier(for me) than doing an interactive rebase:

```
git reset HEAD~2.  // go back 2 commits.
git commit -am “My squashed single commit”
git push --force
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!! or at least get more votes! All other solutions are so complex, and require mass typing frenzy, that a GUI software is better off used (such as sourcetree or tortoise) where you could get the same result only with a few mouse clicks. Your solution, however, is the cleanest, fastest, and great for solo projects, or team projects where you're on a side branch of your own.

Comment: `git reset HEAD~2.` is not a valid command

Comment: @tala9999 What do you mean ? I just used it sucessfully

Comment: What you want is `git reset --soft`. With this solution you'd have to re-add changes to the staging area before making your commit.


See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61171280/10469162

Answer (score 2):

Interactive rebase and merge with reset were mentioned earlier.
Another approach is more safe for me because it doesn't use all previous things (interactive and reset) and doesn't interact into exist data. It uses `git merge --squash`, like the topic starter suggested. It creates a new branch and merge with squash into it:

```
git branch <result_branch_name> <point from where you want to merge commits>
git checkout <result_branch_name>
git merge --squash <branch_with_all_your_commits>
```

As a result you will receive staged changes from all commits between point, where you created the result branch, and the final commit. The commit message will contain all messages from all squashed commits. Then just enter `git commit`, modify the commit message and you will get the only commit with all necessary changes. Original branch can be deleted with `git branch -D <branch_name>`, when you are ready to say it good bye =)