# Git: How to rebase and squash commits from branch to master?

Tags: git, branch, rebase, squash

I'm trying to rebase and squash all my commits from current branch to master. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
git checkout -b new-feature
```

make a couple of commits, after it I was trying:

```
git rebase -i master
```

in this case commits will remain in `new-feature` branch

```
git checkout master
git rebase -i new-feature
```

It gives me and edit window with noop message.

I know about command:

```
git merge --squash new-feature
```

But I'm currently working on learning of `rebase` command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When rebasing, Git will not move commits to another branch. It will move the branch including all its commits. If you want to get the commits into master after rebasing on top of it, use `git merge <branch tip or commit of branch>` to fast-forward the master branch to that commit.

Answer (score 61):

Lets go though the steps.

1 - We create a new feature branch

```
git checkout -b new-feature
```

2 - Now you can add/remove and update whatever you want on your new branch

```
git add <new-file>
git commit -am "Added new file"
git rm <file-name>
git commit -am "Removed a file"
cat "add more stuff to file" >> <new-file>
git commit -am "Updated files"
```

3 - Next, pick and squash any commits down into one nice pretty commit message

```
git rebase -i master
```

The key thing you need to remember here is to change the text that says "pick" to "squash" for all of the commits after the first commit.  This will squash all of the commits down to your master branch.

4 - Select the master branch

```
git checkout master
```

5 - Move the HEAD and the master branch to where new-feature is:

```
git rebase new-feature
```

You can try all of the commands out in this visual tool:
http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/

Comment: You will probably get a 'cannot squash without previous commit' message doing this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563632/how-can-i-merge-two-commits-into-one

Comment: Nice... though I will usually squash my commits `git rebase -i HEAD~##` before the pull/rebase `git pull --rebase origin master`  I just like doing it in two steps which lets me review before/after the rebase.

Comment: This answer looks more suitable than the one picked

Comment: I'd better donot rebase master: `git merge --ff new-feature` instead of `git rebase new-feature`

Comment: A complete answer should go over how to merge in the latest changes to master into the feature branch

Comment: Is there really no command to `git rebase -i` with default of squashing all?  I find myself nearly always wanting to squash my whole feature branch and am surprised there doesn't seem to be a quick shortcut for this (that doesn't involve first counting the precise number of commits, or typing "s" manually next to every commit during the rebase).