# Merge two commits into one and push to remote repo

Tags: git

I want to merge two commits into one. I have seen [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563632/how-can-i-merge-two-commits-into-one) and tried to use squash with rebase but it was not fit me because of I have 2 commits at all and want to merge these 2 commits into 1.
`git log --pretty=oneline` give me:

```
b776cabedd911ba0030537030496ca24102ff7f1 Initial commit.
7b5fb155372b129b38be0c54d184427632d949d4 Second commit.
```

Can someone help?

Comment: can you give a simple explanation of how your tree looks like and which 2 commits you want to squash ?

Comment: Try to use git cherry pick into the branch that you 're working.

Comment: if those are the initial 2 commits in your tree then go with @MichaelWild comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ONLY 2 commit, they can't be merged in common way, because `git rebase -i` then squash need a commit before these 2 commit, which doesn't exists.

So, as you can see on github or other public git repostory, the common way of the first commit is an alomost empty commit, with a empty .gitignore file. This will avoid situation you meet now.

If you really need to merge these 2 commit, here is my answer:

1. Export you 2 commit with `git format-patch -2`
2. Re-create your local git repo using `git init`
3. Apply 2 patch file export in (1) by `git apply 0001*` `git apply 0002*`
4. Commit