# Git: Uncommit without effecting changes

Tags: git, version-control

I have made a few commits to a branch and pushed it to remote. I want to make them into a single commit.
How do I uncommit the previous few commits in a branch without effecting the files?

Answer (score 1):

If you had not pushed the commits to a remote branch,
you could have used e.g. `git rebase -i` to squash the
commits into one. See [How can I merge two commits into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563632/how-can-i-merge-two-commits-into-one/2568581#2568581)

But as the commits are already pushed, there is no
proper way instead of overwriting the history, which is usually a bad idea
especially if others have already pulled your changes.

If you can do it, use `git rebase` as described above and then see [Force "git push" to overwrite remote files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510462/force-git-push-to-overwrite-remote-files) .