# Git merge the two commit messages into one message

Tags: git, github, merge, gitlab, git-merge

I'm beginner in GIT. I did some changes in my working project and created the the test branch using

```
git checkout -b 'test'
```

I committed my changes twice.

```
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git push --set-upstream origin test
```

Again I did some changes and committed changes

```
git add .
git commit -m "second commit"
git push --set-upstream origin test
```

Now I created **pull request** . What exactly want is, I have two commits now. When I merge into master branch, I dont want see those two commit messages, I want to merge those messages "first commit" and "second commit" into one message and merge into master branch.

I tried rebase and rest commands. May be I'm using in wrong way. Can any one help me out this.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to merge two last commits into one with a given name

```
git reset --soft "HEAD^"
git commit --amend
```

Comment: Thanks you.. after git commit.. Do I need to push the branch again ?

Comment: Yes, if you need to update your source code on github

Comment: Make sure that the last commits on github are yours and use
git push --set-upstream origin test --force

Comment: the error happens because you try to rename commits that are already pushed to github

Comment: so you need to use --force option

Comment: Thank you so much.. It worked :)

Comment: Good, be careful with --force option.If you push using it you'll get exactly the same commits on github as you have locally

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to merge the two commits into a new branch as a single commit, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19554373/1992360) answer.

> Assuming you were in your own topic branch. If you want to merge the
> last 2 commits into one and look like a hero, branch off the commit
> just before you made the last two commits.
>
> **git checkout -b temp_branch HEAD^2**
>
> Then squash commit the other branch
> in this new branch:
>
> **git merge branch_with_two_commits --squash**
>
> That will bring in the
> changes but not commit them. So just commit them and you're done.
>
> **git commit -m "my message"**
>
> Now you can merge this new topic branch
> back into your main branch.

If you just want to merge the two commits into one in your current directory before pushing the code, then use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24690646/1992360) answer.

> If there are multiple commits, you can use git rebase -i to squash two
> commits into one.
>
> If there are only two commits you want to merge, and they are the
> "most recent two", the following commands can be used to combine the
> two commits into one:
>
> git reset --soft "HEAD^"
>
> git commit --amend

Safe to say that it is a duplicate but I wanted you to have links to the answer you are looking for.