# Which one is my previous commit when running interactive rebase?

Tags: git, rebase, squash, git-squash, git-interactive-rebase

When I run something like `git rebase -i --rebase-merges eeb1425e0` my commits list is showed upside down, i.e., the first commit is the last and the last commit is the first:

```java
pick A Penultimate commit
pick B Penult commmit
pick C Latest commit

# Rebase eeb1425e..5a3f045b onto eeb1425e (288 commands)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
# r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit <commit> = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash <commit> = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup <commit> = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec <command> = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# b, break = stop here (continue rebase later with 'git rebase --continue')
# d, drop <commit> = remove commit
# l, label <label> = label current HEAD with a name
# t, reset <label> = reset HEAD to a label
# m, merge [-C <commit> | -c <commit>] <label> [# <oneline>]
# .       create a merge commit using the original merge commit's
# .       message (or the oneline, if no original merge commit was
# .       specified). Use -c <commit> to reword the commit message.
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

Then, when the squash option says `squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit`, and I push `squash` as following:

```java
pick A Penultimate commit
squash B Penult commmit
pick C Latest commit
```

The previous commit of `B` is `A` or `C`? Is `B` going to be merged/squashed with `A` or `C`?

Related to:

1. [How can I merge two commits into one if I already started rebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563632/how-can-i-merge-two-commits-into-one-if-i-already-started-rebase)
2. [What exactly does git's "rebase --preserve-merges" do (and why?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915430/what-exactly-does-gits-rebase-preserve-merges-do-and-why)

Comment: It seems as if the answer to your question should be obvious if you proceed with the interactive rebase. When you submit the pick list, which commits get merged?

Comment: Not an expert, but if the interactive rebase proceeds in order A, B, C, I would think the previous commit of B would be A. B would be combined into A is what it looks like to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commit ordering is is indeed reversed from what you normally see with `git log`, so for:

> ```
> pick A Penultimate commit
> pick B Penult commmit
> pick C Latest commit
> ```

if you change the second line to read `squash`, Git will:

- cherry-pick commit `A` to *begin* making a new commit, but not make it yet;
- squash commit `B` into that before actually making the new commit; and
- cherry-pick commit `C` to make a second new commit;

giving you what I like to draw, pictorially, as:

```
          A--B--C   [abandoned]
         /
...--o--o--AB--C'   <-- branch-name
```

Here the `A-B-C` chain are the original three commits, with the last one drawn on the right (rather than top or bottom), and the new `AB-C'` chain are the two new commits, again with the last one drawn on the right.  Your branch name used to identify commit `C`, and now identifies new copy `C'`.

---

Side note: the word for third-from-last is *antepenultimate*.  "Penultimate" literally means ["second from last"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/penultimate).  If there is a fourth from last you need to identify, this is the [*preantepenultimate*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/preantepenultimate).  There appears to be no English-language word for "fifth from last".  Following links here arrives at [*propreantepenultimate*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/propreantepenultimate#English), but see [the status at the Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/submission/6431/propreantepenultimate) for instance.

Another side note: interactive rebase is willing to make and then unmake commits, so the description above ("squash before actually making commit") is just shorthand for what you'll *see* when you look at results, rather than a full description of the underlying machinery.  The actual set of commits may include extra abandoned temporary commits.  Git will clean all of these up on its own eventually.